# Accessing C# Variable from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, hidden-field

In my MS SQL table, I read in an "time_zone" for a city from a record.

I then want to use this time zone in a Javascript function to create a digital clock for that city.

Currently I am trying to set the time_zone variable from

Here's a code snippet from Default.aspx:

```
            function showtime() {
                 zone(hiddenZone,clock);
            }
        window.onload = showtime;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <span id="clock"></span>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenZone" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblXml" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The only C# I have in my Default.aspx.cs for is:

```
hiddenZone.Value=timeZone;
```

I've checked and timeZone has the correct value read in from the database.

The error message I receive from the JS in the "showtime" function is: "hiddenZone is undefined"

How can I get the "timeZone" C# variable into my Javascript and use it for the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check against the hiddenZone ClientID.

```
function showtime() {
                 zone(
                      document.getElementById('<%=hiddenZone.ClientID%>'),
                      clock
                   );
            }
```

ASP.NET creates a new names for objects it creates on the HTML page, so they won't be the same as what you specify the id to be.

Comment: With .NET 4.0's ClientIdMode property, you will have more flexibility in situations like this.
http://www.dotnetcube.com/post/Overview-of-NET-40-features-e28093-ASPNET-40-ClientIDMode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use your existing code by replacing:

```
function showtime() {
    zone(hiddenZone, 'clock');
}
```

with

```
function showtime() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenZone.ClientID %>');
    // if you are using ASP.NET AJAX use:
    // var elem = $get('<%= hiddenZone.ClientID %>');

    zone(elem.value, 'clock');
}
```

I'm not sure what your 'zone' function does either.  But something like this may point you in the right direction if you are also having difficulties with it as well:

```
function zone(tz, dispID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(dispID);
    // if you are using ASP.NET AJAX use:
    // var elem = $get(dispID);

    elem.innerHTML = tz;
}
```

Alternatively, if it were a public property on your page you can remove your reference to the asp:HiddenField and just use:

```
function showtime() {
    zone(<%= MyFormsTimeZoneProperty %>, clock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in server side tags,

```
        function showtime() {
             zone('<%= hiddenZone.Value %>',clock);
        }
```